# How to create Expandable MultiLevel Menus in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-menu, android-json

I want to create a Expandable Multi-level (three level) menus and fill data dynamics. My data come from web server i want to fill data directly into menus and I also want First Level Menus and Second level is already open. I am new in android developing.Thanks in advance!

I give a reference below image:-

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_enter, menu);
    SubMenu submenu = menu.addSubMenu(0, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, "My Account");
    //submenu.add(0, 10, Menu.NONE, "My Profile");
    //submenu.add(0, 15, Menu.NONE, "Change Job");
    SubMenu submenu2 = submenu.addSubMenu(0, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, "Change Job");
    submenu2.add(0, 100, Menu.NONE, "Pilot");
    submenu2.add(0, 105, Menu.NONE, "Fligh Attendant");
    submenu2.add(0, 110, Menu.NONE, "Technical");
    //submenu.add(0, 20, Menu.NONE, "Log Out");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: alican, this is a setting menu, but I want drawer menu just I given in the image above